# How to Find Current Month and Year From Custom Date range?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a problem about custom date range. let me explain it, for our company month count from current month day 21 to next month day 20. if i want to know which employee join current month then normally i can find using sql

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblEmployeeMaster
  --CURRENT MONTH
  WHERE MONTH(DateOfJoining)=MONTH(GETDATE())  AND YEAR(DateOfJoining)=YEAR(GETDATE())
```

but for this custom date range i can not find employee who are join in this month. For example in this system if i want to find list of employee joined in this month then result will be show that employee who join in previous month  after day 21 to current month day 20. Could someone please help me?

Comment: which custom date range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example, this month's period is considered to be from 21 of the previous month to 20 of current month, employees in that period are considered to be this month's employees (all who came to company after 2012-05-21 until 2012-06-20 (including 2012-06-20)). Try it:

```
SELECT  DateOfJoining,
        DATEADD(DAY, 20, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) PeriodStart,
        DATEADD(DAY, 19, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) PeriodEnd
FROM    tblEmployeeMaster
WHERE   DateOfJoining > DATEADD(DAY, 20, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
        AND 
        DateOfJoining < DATEADD(DAY, 20, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

Comment: There is one more thing, if DateOfJoining contains dates together with time, for instance '2012-06-20 13:00:00' and you want employees who came that day, WHERE condition should be changed to:  WHERE   DateOfJoining > DATEADD(DAY, 20, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)) 
   AND 
   DateOfJoining < DATEADD(DAY, 20, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0))

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM tblEmployeeMaster  
WHERE DateOfJoining BETWEEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) +'-'+ CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) +'-21' AS DATETIME)
AND CAST(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) +'-'+ CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) +'-20' AS DATETIME)
```